# copy all contents of a td to another in another div

Tags: php, jquery

I do need to know how to copy the contents of an entire html td td and play for another from a different button that was clicked?

both the button when the content comes from the database

was thinking about this for jquery but not know where to start: (

Comment: In this StackOverflow page just take a look at the menu at the right under : **RELATED** you'll find your answer (not only one...). (Have you done any research on that matter before asking?)

Comment: RTLM? http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 0):

This should go with:

```
$('td').clone().appendTo('.newtd');
```

you trigger that with eg following:

```
$('#triggerbtn').click(function() { 
     $('td').clone().appendTo('.newtd');
   }
```

markup for the button:

```
<div id="triggerbtn">Click me for clone</div>
```

the `.newtd` is the class of the new `td` you want to clone your content. you can use an `id` declared with a `#newtd` as well.

Comment: ok but how do and the button?

Comment: @DanielSwater please don't use **Google Translate** to ask questions :) a piece of code speaks all languages and you showed us none.